# Why does start transaction and rollback fail to rollback when running scripts in MySQL 5?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

I have the following script...

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO `Image` (`id`,`created`,`deleted`,`fileName`,`used`) VALUES (-114, NULL, NULL, 'c21_1.jpg', NULL);
INSERT INTO `Image` (`id`,`created`,`deleted`,`fileName`,`used`) VALUES (-115, NULL, NULL, 'c21_2.jpg', NULL);
INSERT INTO `Image` (`id`,`created`,`deleted`,`fileName`,`used`) VALUES (-116, NULL, NULL, 'c21_3.jpg', NULL);
INSERT INTO `Image` (`id`,`created`,`deleted`,`fileName`,`used`) VALUES (-117, NULL, NULL, 'c21_4.gif', NULL);
INSERT INTO `Image` (`id`,`created`,`deleted`,`fileName`,`used`) VALUES (-118, NULL, NULL, 'c21_5.gif', NULL);
INSERT INTO `Image` (`id`,`created`,`deleted`,`fileName`,`used`) VALUES (-119, NULL, NULL, 'c21_6.gif', NULL);
INSERT INTO `Image` (`id`,`created`,`deleted`,`fileName`,`used`) VALUES (-120, NULL, NULL, 'c21_7.gif', NULL);
INSERT INTO `Image` (`id`,`created`,`deleted`,`fileName`,`used`) VALUES (-121, NULL, NULL, 'AIRMILES_MIN_RBLUE.png', NULL);
INSERT INTO `Image` (`id`,`created`,`deleted`,`fileName`,`used`) VALUES (-122, NULL, NULL, 'c21_logo_commercial-WHT.png', NULL);
INSERT INTO `Image` (`id`,`created`,`deleted`,`fileName`,`used`) VALUES (-123, NULL, NULL, 'c21_logo_fhe_pms124-WHT.png', NULL);
INSERT INTO `Image` (`id`,`created`,`deleted`,`fileName`,`used`) VALUES (-124, NULL, NULL, 'CENTURY-21-Logo-Century21.png', NULL);
INSERT INTO `Image` (`id`,`created`,`deleted`,`fileName`,`used`) VALUES (-125, NULL, NULL, 'Easter-Seals-Logos-2005-008-1.png', NULL);
INSERT INTO `Image` (`id`,`created`,`deleted`,`fileName`,`used`) VALUES (-126, NULL, NULL, 'Easter-Seals-Logos-2005-008-2.png', NULL);
INSERT INTO `Image` (`id`,`created`,`deleted`,`fileName`,`used`) VALUES (-127, NULL, NULL, 'kids-to-camp-EN.png', NULL);



INSERT INTO `AgencyImage` (`agency_id`,`image_id`) VALUES   (1, -115);
INSERT INTO `AgencyImage` (`agency_id`,`image_id`) VALUES   (1, -116);
INSERT INTO `AgencyImage` (`agency_id`,`image_id`) VALUES   (1, -117);
INSERT INTO `AgencyImage` (`agency_id`,`image_id`) VALUES   (1, -118);
INSERT INTO `AgencyImage` (`agency_id`,`image_id`) VALUES   (1, -119);
INSERT INTO `AgencyImage` (`agency_id`,`image_id`) VALUES   (1, -120);
INSERT INTO `AgencyImage` (`agency_id`,`image_id`) VALUES   (1, -121);
INSERT INTO `AgencyImage` (`agency_id`,`image_id`) VALUES   (1, -122);
INSERT INTO `AgencyImage` (`agency_id`,`image_id`) VALUES   (1, -123);
INSERT INTO `AgencyImage` (`agency_id`,`image_id`) VALUES   (1, -124);
INSERT INTO `AgencyImage` (`agency_id`,`image_id`) VALUES   (1, -125);
INSERT INTO `AgencyImage` (`agency_id`,`image_id`) VALUES   (1, -126);
INSERT INTO `AgencyImage` (`agency_id`,`image_id`) VALUES   (1, -127);


ROLLBACK;
```

I wanted to validate the script ran before commiting the code.  However the first time this ran it did not roll anything back.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you think you are doing something wrong?

Comment: Because if he's using a transactional storage engine (e.g. InnoDB), after the ROLLBACK; at the bottom, the rows will not be present.

Comment: King Skippus, please don't make silly comments.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a MyISAM table?  If so, you need to [switch to InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html) if you want to use transactions.  If you're running the queries from something like PHP, make sure you have [autocommit](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php) turned off.

Comment: I am running it from the Intellij query tool that is built into the IDE.

Comment: When you create your table, try putting ENGINE=InnoDB on the end.  For example: CREATE TABLE ( /* column definitions */ ) ENGINE=InnoDB;  If that works, you were using a non-transactional engine (probably MyISAM) before.  I don't know anything about Intellij; if it has a GUI for creating tables, check to see if there is an option for creating them as InnoDB tables instead of MyISAM.  I have a sneaky suspicion that's what's happening.

Comment: By the way, if you want all of your tables and databases to use InnoDB by default instead of MyISAM so that you have transactions always enabled, consider changing your default storage engine in your my.conf file.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-storage-engine

Comment: Autocommit does not need to be turned off. If you start a transaction with `start transaction` the status of autocommit is irrelevant. After the commit/rollback autocommit will be re-enabled. **if** you turn autocommit off you will need to do a manual commit after every insert/delete/update or nothing will happen.